# XML Linq in C# (YouTube API)

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone help me out real quick, im writing something that is using the Youtube API and it gives me results in XML, i am trying to get a title of the vid from the XML response.

Here is a link to the XML : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/T7sIiqq66rk?v=2

Here is my code:

```
string nameURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2";
WebRequest nameRequest = WebRequest.Create(nameURL);
HttpWebResponse nameResponse = (HttpWebResponse)nameRequest.GetResponse();
Stream nameStream = nameResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader nameReader = new StreamReader(nameStream);
string XML = nameReader.ReadToEnd();
var VideoInfo = from e in XElement.Parse(XML).Elements("entry") select new {Id = e.Element("title").Value};
Console.WriteLine(VideoInfo.FirstOrDefault().Id);
```

The debugger seems to be breaking on the WriteLine method, saying its null, i have tried some other ways as well but cants seem to get just the title element.

Edit: There is something wrong that's causing the the results to be null, i have established that, but could someone point out why it keeps returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `VideoInfo.FirstOrDefault()` will return null if there are no entries, so it will throw an exception when you try to access the `Id` field.

Since `entry` is the root element, you should access XDocument.Root, and not `Elements("entry")`

Your code should be more like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(XML);

var VideoInfo = new {Id = xDoc.Root.Element("id").Value };

Console.WriteLine(VideoInfo.Id);
```

Comment: do you have any idea as to why the field is null?

Comment: you cant do that, there is no Root property

Comment: Not for XElement, but for XDocument

Comment: That doesnt work it outputs the whole root element, i also just  tried :var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(XML);

            var VideoInfo = new { Id = xDoc.Root.Element("title").Value };

            Console.WriteLine(VideoInfo.Id);

Comment: Yeah, true, but I'm just giving you pointers. In the end, you'll be the one that will have to implement it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, i have a feeling that you answer should work and there is something larger at fault here, so i will mark it as the answer i gues s.